# Tkinter store choices- values inside variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to play and learn with tkinter :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

gui = Tk(className='STUDENTS')
gui.geometry("500x300")


def openNewWindow2():
    newWindow1 = Toplevel(gui)
    newWindow1.title("STUDENTS")
    newWindow1.geometry("500x300")
    Label(newWindow1, text='Select How many students?').pack()
    options2 = [
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
    ]
    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set("1")
    drop = OptionMenu(newWindow1, clicked, *options2)
    drop.pack()
    btn5 = Button(newWindow1,
                  text="GENERATE!!!",
                  command"#some function to use the values of dropdown and maxcal#")
    btn5.pack(pady=20)
    maxcal = DateEntry(newWindow1, width=12, background='darkblue',
                foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    maxcal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

label = Label(gui, text='test1~')
label.pack(pady=10)
btn2 = Button(gui,
              text="generator",
              command=openNewWindow2)

btn2.pack(pady=20)
gui.mainloop()
```

This will create a window with a dropdown menu. I want to hit the `btn5` and store  the values of the dropdown menu and the calendar in another window after.
Is this possible?

Comment: You can store it in a variable and make it `global`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I am not familiar with tkinter. Can you tell my which line to store in variable? I printed everything of this and nothing showed the values I chose

Comment: I am not sure, what you want, so create a function, link it with the button and then inside the function say, `var = clicked.get(),maxcal.get()` and `print(var)` to see it.

Comment: I did it but it sends only the default value the 1

Comment: I want to choose for example 5 in the dropdown and print 5 times "hello world" with another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, something like this should work:

```
def openNewWindow2():
    newWindow1 = Toplevel(gui)
    def func():
        print('hello world'*int(clicked.get()))

    ....
    btn5 = Button(newWindow1,text="GENERATE!!!",command=func)
```

It is something *special* with python that I don't think any other programing languages offer. You can multiply a string(I guess all iterables) with an integer to repeat it that many times.

Comment: The new func is inside the openNewWindow2() ? Alsο in the btn5 I put in the command= func() do I have to put also the clicked?

Comment: @DrGenius That was the problem, dont put `func()`. Check updated answer

Comment: And how the code understands that every time the btn5 is pressed to do the multiply ?

Comment: @DrGenius `clicked.get()` is the number of times it should be multiplied. When that changes, the number of times multiplied will also change.

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot. but I still dont undestand  what is the difference func and func()

Comment: @DrGenius When you say `func()` it will directly call the  function. But when you say `func` it will call the function only when you press the button.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you a lot for your time and your help.